# How I can fix delta symbol at each colone of my below sign table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have realized a table of sign of $|x+1|-|x+2|+|x-3|$ as shown in the picture , but i have a problem to fix the delta symbole in colone for example for $|x+1|$ i want to fix the delta symbol only at colone of   $x=-1$ ,the same with $|x+2|$ only at $x=-2$ and  $|x-3|$ only at $x=3$ ? , My question how I can do that?

**Note**:I mean by delta symbole black dot in colone

[image]

This is my code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=6,espcl=3,deltacl=0]
      {x /.8, $|x+1|$ /.8, $|x+2|$ /.8, $|x-3|$ /.8,$p(x)=|x+1|-|x+2|+|x-3|$/.8}
      {$-\infty$,$-2$,$-1$,$3$,$+\infty$} % four main references
    \tkzTabLine {,-x-1,t,-x-1,z,x+1,z,x+1} % seven denotations
    \tkzTabLine {,-x-2,z,x+2,t,x+2,z,x+2}
    \tkzTabLine {,-x+3,z,-x+3,z,-x+3,z,x+3}
    \tkzTabLine {,4-x,z,-3x,z,2-x,z,2+x}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=6,espcl=3,deltacl=0]
      {x /.8, $|x+1|$ /.8, $|x+2|$ /.8, $|x-3|$ /.8,$p(x)=|x+1|-|x+2|+|x-3|$/.8}
      {$-\infty$,$-2$,$-1$,$3$,$+\infty$} % four main references                                               
    \tkzTabLine {,-x-1,t,-x-1,z,x+1,t,x+1} % seven denotations                                                 
    \tkzTabLine {,-x-2,z,x+2,t,x+2,t,x+2}
    \tkzTabLine {,-x+3,t,-x+3,t,-x+3,z,x-3}
    \tkzTabLine {,4-x,t,-3x,t,2-x,t,x-4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pleas try to compile again, you have a wrong in summation in the  last line of table for p(x) , you have |x+1|-|x+2|+|x-3| not  |x+1|+|x+2|+|x-3|